# Change C# resource name

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, dll, resources

I'm working on a C# project using WPF and Resources for multi-language support. My question is: in my solution explorer this resources are located in ProjectName/Resources/Languages/Res.en.resx and so on (en becomes it for italian or fr for french), but when compiling I get in my main folder some "en", "it", "fr" direcories, each one with a "AppName.resources.dll" inside. Is there a way to change these DLLs names so that I can distinguish between them not only looking at the folder they are located in?

Comment: why bother change it?

Comment: No you can't. The folder name is defined by how .Net probes for localised assemblies.

Comment: I understand for the folder name, but there isn't a way also to change dlls names?

Comment: Not as far as I know...